# Why does emacs' comint-send-string behave differently in different derived modes?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've been fooling around with comint-mode lately and I'm noticing some weird behaviors. Its very poorly documented, so I'm wondering if anyone has any insight on this.

In some modes, `comint-send-string` causes whatever is sent to be inserted into the comint buffer *and then* sent to the associated process, whereas in others, the input is send directly to the process without being placed into the buffer. For example, do `run-python` with the new (24.3) python.el and then do `(comint-send-string "*Python*" "x=3\n")`, the string `x=3` is inserted into the buffer and then executed. If you do `M-x shell`, however, and then `(comint-send-string "*shell*" "x=3\n")`, no text is inserted into the buffer, the input is simply sent to the shell process directly to be executed.

Does anyone know why this difference in behavior exists or how I can change it?

Comment: You are using calling conventions of `comint-send-string` but talking about `comint-send-input` - please clarify your question.

Comment: whoops, sorry, you're right. I'm talking about `comint-send-string`, will edit. The use of `comint-send-input` is totally clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. For some reason the system python on OSX causes this behavior, installing python from homebrew fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I observe identical behavior on linux (`emacs-version` == `"24.3.50.7"`, both GUI and `emacs -Q -nw`): neither

```
(comint-send-string "*Python*" "x=3\n")
```

nor

```
(comint-send-string "*shell*" "x=3\n")
```

insert anything in the `comint` buffer (i.e., the next prompt appears
right after the previous prompt - without even a newline between them).

Comment: Interesting; it appears to be an issue with running emacs in a GUI. I observe the behavior described above in Cocoa emacs (Emacs.app) even with all my configuration turned off, but not when run from a terminal.

Comment: This might be an apple artefact then, I see the same behavior with and w/o GUI on linux.

Comment: Hmmm upon further investigation, the GUI appears not to be the problem; trying it again on the terminal gives the behavior I describe above. It worked *once*, but not again afterwords. You're right that it could be some artefact of compiling on OSX. I'll ask other OSX users I know what they see. Strange.

Comment: How about using `(comint-send-input)` following the `(comint-send-string . . .`)?  If the `\n` was intended to be the equivalent of `comint-send-input`, then `\n` will no longer be needed.